# Can't mount share in VirtualBox guest

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, gentoo, guest-additions

I'm attempting to mount a share in a guest OS in VirtualBox:

```
$ mount -t vboxsf share /mnt/share
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: No such device
```

If I click the folder icon in the corner, and click "Shared Folders Settings...", I see: "share" "/Users/me/tmp/vm-transfer" "" "Full", and if I double click the row:

> Folder Path: /Users/me/tmp/vm-transfer
>
> Folder Name: share
>
> (unchecked) Read-only
>
> (unchecked) Auto-mount
>
> (unchecked) Make Permanent

The guest has the guest extensions installed:

```
$ lsmod
Module         Size  Used by
vboxvideo      1838  1
vboxguest    163929  1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `modprobe vboxsf` before trying to mount the share.

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaving the [very useful answer from @user287782](https://superuser.com/a/776284/39876) marked as the accepted answer, because it's the root of the problem. In my case, I'm using Gentoo, and on Gentoo, the "VirtualBox guest additions" install themselves as an `init.d` script, so they can be started with:

```
/etc/init.d/virtualbox-guest-additions start
```

Or better,

```
eselect rc start virtualbox-guest-additions
```

To make this happen automatically,

```
eselect rc add virtualbox-guest-additions default
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your user has administrative permission or it's in `vboxsf` group:

```
sudo usermod -g vboxsf user
```

or mount it with `root` permission by prefixing your command with `sudo`.

Also consider installing [VBox Guest Additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) for share folder support and [VirtualBox Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) for extra support for certain devices.

See also: [Shared folder in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/q/103069/78223).